# I do not understand this warning: The method or function should not be given explicit type argument(s)

Tags: f#

I have this code:

```
type BSCReply =
    {
        status:  int
        message: string
        result:  string
    }

let private decodeResult<'a> (result: IRestResponse) =
    let deserialize content =
        try
            Ok (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'b> content)
        with ex ->
            Error (HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Humanize())

    match result.IsSuccessful with
    | true  ->  match deserialize<BSCReply> result.Content with
                | Ok r    -> deserialize<'a> r.result
                | Error e -> Error e
    | false ->  Error(result.StatusCode, result.ErrorMessage)
```

but when compiling, I get this error:

> [FS0686] The method or function 'deserialize' should not be given explicit type argument(s) because it does not declare its type parameters explicitly

the warning happens two times, one for each use of 'deserialize'

I don't understand this error, can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that `deserialize` refers to a type `'b` that you haven't defined anywhere. To fix this, you should move `deserialize` out to the top level and declare `'b` explicitly. Something like this:

```
let private deserialize<'b> content =
    try
        Ok (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'b> content)
    with ex ->
        Error (HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Humanize())

let private decodeResult<'a> (result: IRestResponse) =
    match result.IsSuccessful with
    | true  ->  match deserialize<BSCReply> result.Content with
                | Ok r    -> deserialize<'a> r.result
                | Error e -> Error e
    | false ->  Error(result.StatusCode, result.ErrorMessage)
```

Comment: I tried to define 'b while inside the decodeResult function, but the compiler won't let me; why is that? also I thought that maybe if I made deserialize inline it would then allow me, but it wasn't the case either

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not sure why the F# compiler doesn't support explicit type parameters for a nested function.

Comment: I think I'll open a new question specifically to try to understand that; it seems like it could be useful, as in this case, and I'm curious if there is a real reason behind it.

Comment: I posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987687/why-doesnt-the-f-compiler-support-excplicit-types-inside-a-nested-function