# Why doesn't the F# compiler support excplicit types inside a nested function?

Tags: f#

This is a followup of question [I do not understand this warning: The method or function should not be given explicit type argument(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978512/i-do-not-understand-this-warning-the-method-or-function-should-not-be-given-exp/66978813#66978813)

The code in question was:

```
type BSCReply =
    {
        status:  int
        message: string
        result:  string
    }

let private decodeResult<'a> (result: IRestResponse) =
    let deserialize content =
        try
            Ok (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'b> content)
        with ex ->
            Error (HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Humanize())

    match result.IsSuccessful with
    | true  ->  match deserialize<BSCReply> result.Content with
                | Ok r    -> deserialize<'a> r.result
                | Error e -> Error e
    | false ->  Error(result.StatusCode, result.ErrorMessage)
```

and the compiler would warn:

> [FS0686] The method or function 'deserialize' should not be given explicit type argument(s) because it does not declare its type parameters explicitly

The answer to the question solved the issue by moving the nested function to the outer scope.

I also cannot do: `let deserialize<'b> content =` and I also tried to inline it, but to no avail.

My question here is:

Why doesn't the compiler allow for this? is there a specific reason? or just not enough use cases were raised at design time?

Comment: Does `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<'a>` work? Seems like the issue is that generics are there so that the caller can provide the concrete type. If the generic is inner to the function and not exposed to the caller it can't serve a purpose.

Comment: Ideally I’d pass the type to the deserialize function so the generic in the json concert call would have the type, but the compiler won’t let me add it to the deserialize inner function

Comment: I read the code again and now understand what you're trying to do. I believe the issue is inner functions actually get compiled as objects (as the outer function's parameters are in scope). It was probably taken as too much effort to allow the compiler to compile the closures as generic but would be interested to hear from a more authoritative source.